Power BI Time Increment Column in Multiple Time Sei
I have combined multiple time series data files in power BI. I need to create a column with incremented test time from 0 for each of the [category].
Below is the sample table.
enter image description here
Eventually I want to create column looking like this.
enter image description here
There will be hundreds of categories (which is essentially file names from combined files) and thousands of the steps. The reason of doing this is that the time interval between the [Steps] can be different per each category (1 seconds ~ 300 seconds).
Can anyone help please?
I am new Power BI and could not touch the problem. Expecting DAX code?

Assuming the Absolute Time increases with each row:
TestTime = 
VAR CurrentAbsoluteTime = 'Table'[Absolute Time]
var NextAbsoluteTime = 
    CALCULATE(
        MIN('Table'[Absolute Time]),
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            'Table'[Absolute Time] > CurrentAbsoluteTime
        )
    )

return

(NextAbsoluteTime-CurrentAbsoluteTime)*'Table'[Steps]


you can create an index column in PQ

and use DAX to create a column
Column=
VAR _next =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Index] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Index] ) + 1 ),
        'Table'[Absolut Time]
    )
RETURN
    ( _next - 'Table'[Absolut Time] ) * 'Table'[Steps]


